# HDFS: No such file or directory

Tags: hdfs

I have a hdfs node, when I tried to upload file to it, I get No such file or directory error, here is the screenshot:

[image]

if I do `hdfs dfs -put test.txt /Manager/test.txt`

I will get this error: `put: Current inode is not a directory: Manager(INodeFile@54cc0f8), parentDir=/`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? and how to fix it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you are a Windows user, not Unix/Linux. You may want to refer to this [book](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/Teach.Yourself.Linux.In.24.Hours.pdf) for more practice reference.

Comment: Two things to note:
1. hdfs dfs -put -f Manager (This command tries to look for Manager file or folder in edge node and place it in hdfs forcefully replacing existing file under hdfs home dir of the user. Failed as no file or folder names Manager is present in edge node.)
2. hdfs dfs -put test.txt /Manager/test.txt (Here command tries to place test.txt into folder Manager looking it from root(/) folder of hdfs. Failed as no folder called Manager exists in hdfs root'/')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, I should have the code written as:

```
hdfs dfs -put test.txt Manager
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your test.txt located?